# how to set path in servlets to store downloaded images in my web application,i want to store images in project folder

Tags: servlets

java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\WebContent\EPaper1\MILAP1\23_10_2014_1.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(Unknown Source)

Comment: No, you don't want to store the files in the project folder. Your app will be deployed on a server where there is no project folder. The project folder only exists on a developer workstation. Configure an absolute path where files should be stored, and use this absolute path.

Comment: thanks for ur response ,i solved my problem @JB Nizet